# Scale Div and child element

Tags: html, css

So I got this pixel image maded with divs

```css
#dibujo {
  margin: auto;
  width: 390px;
  height: 600px;
}
#dibujo div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  float: left;
}
body {
  background-color: rgb(51, 173, 255);
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#red {
  background-color: rgb(230, 0, 0);
}
#orange {
  background-color: rgb(230, 92, 0);
}
#black {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
#pink {
  background-color: rgb(255, 51, 153);
}
#gray {
  background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
}
#darkGray {
  background-color: rgb(38, 38, 38);
}
#white {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="http://fezgame.com/">
    <div id="dibujo">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div id="orange"></div>
      <div id="red"></div>
      <div id="red"></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>

      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div id="orange"></div>
      <div id="red"></div>
      <div id="red"></div>
      <div id="red"></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>

      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div id="red"></div>
      <div id="red"></div>
      <div id="red"></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>

      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>

      <div></div>
      <div id="darkGray"></div>
      <div id="gray"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div></div>

      <div id="darkGray"></div>
      <div id="gray"></div>
      <div id="gray"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>

      <div id="darkGray"></div>
      <div id="gray"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="black"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="black"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>

      <div id="darkGray"></div>
      <div id="gray"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="black"></div>
      <div id="black"></div>
      <div id="black"></div>
      <div id="black"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>

      <div id="darkGray"></div>
      <div id="gray"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="pink"></div>
      <div id="pink"></div>
      <div id="black"></div>
      <div id="black"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>

      <div id="darkGray"></div>
      <div id="gray"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="pink"></div>
      <div id="black"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>

      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>

      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div id="darkGray"></div>
      <div id="gray"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div></div>

      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div id="darkGray"></div>
      <div id="darkGray"></div>
      <div id="gray"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>

      <div></div>
      <div id="darkGray"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="gray"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="darkGray"></div>
      <div id="darkGray"></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>

      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div id="darkGray"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="darkGray"></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>

      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div id="darkGray"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>

      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div id="darkGray"></div>
      <div id="gray"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>

      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div id="darkGray"></div>
      <div id="gray"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div id="white"></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>

      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div id="darkGray"></div>
      <div id="gray"></div>
      <div id="darkGray"></div>
      <div id="darkGray"></div>
      <div id="gray"></div>
      <div id="darkGray"></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>

      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div id="darkGray"></div>
      <div id="gray"></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div id="darkGray"></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </a>
</body>
```

The CSS has got a fixed size for the image, how can I change the CSS to make the div and the child reizable? I tried to make the #dibujo width: 30%; and the #dibujo div width: 10% but th entire image disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using viewport width/height and CSS `calc()` will give you this

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(51, 173, 255);
}
#dibujo {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50vw;                    /*  viewport width to scale   */
  height: 80vh;                   /*  viewport height to scale  */
}
#dibujo div {
  width: calc(100% / 13);         /*  divide 13 div per row with 100% of parent   */
  height: calc(100% / 13);        /*  divide 13 row of div's with 100% of parent  */
  float: left;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#red {
  background-color: rgb(230, 0, 0);
}
#orange {
  background-color: rgb(230, 92, 0);
}
#black {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
#pink {
  background-color: rgb(255, 51, 153);
}
#gray {
  background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
}
#darkGray {
  background-color: rgb(38, 38, 38);
}
#white {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<a href="http://fezgame.com/">
  <div id="dibujo">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div id="orange"></div>
    <div id="red"></div>
    <div id="red"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>

    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div id="orange"></div>
    <div id="red"></div>
    <div id="red"></div>
    <div id="red"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>

    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div id="red"></div>
    <div id="red"></div>
    <div id="red"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>

    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>

    <div></div>
    <div id="darkGray"></div>
    <div id="gray"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div></div>

    <div id="darkGray"></div>
    <div id="gray"></div>
    <div id="gray"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>

    <div id="darkGray"></div>
    <div id="gray"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="black"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="black"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>

    <div id="darkGray"></div>
    <div id="gray"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="black"></div>
    <div id="black"></div>
    <div id="black"></div>
    <div id="black"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>

    <div id="darkGray"></div>
    <div id="gray"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="pink"></div>
    <div id="pink"></div>
    <div id="black"></div>
    <div id="black"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>

    <div id="darkGray"></div>
    <div id="gray"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="pink"></div>
    <div id="black"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>

    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>

    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div id="darkGray"></div>
    <div id="gray"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div></div>

    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div id="darkGray"></div>
    <div id="darkGray"></div>
    <div id="gray"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>

    <div></div>
    <div id="darkGray"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="gray"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="darkGray"></div>
    <div id="darkGray"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>

    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div id="darkGray"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="darkGray"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>

    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div id="darkGray"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>

    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div id="darkGray"></div>
    <div id="gray"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>

    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div id="darkGray"></div>
    <div id="gray"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>

    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div id="darkGray"></div>
    <div id="gray"></div>
    <div id="darkGray"></div>
    <div id="darkGray"></div>
    <div id="gray"></div>
    <div id="darkGray"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>

    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div id="darkGray"></div>
    <div id="gray"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div id="darkGray"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thnks

Answer (score 0):

Change the width of #dibujo to 30%, and then change the width of the inside divs to 7.69%, which is 100 divided by your number of divs -> 100/13. The same is with the height.

```
#dibujo{
margin: auto;
width: 30%;
height: 600px;
}
#dibujo div{
width: 7.69%;
height: 30px;
float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`width` and `height` behave differently for a block element.  For example, if you set the width on a div to be a 20%, it will adjust relative to the window as you shrink the window.  The same is not true for height - the height will not resize as you shrink the window.

To make the height adjust as you resize (shrink) the window, you will have to set `position: absolute;`.  The issue then becomes positioning your divs.  This will require specifying `top` and maybe `left` rules, which you can also do as percentages.  So, basically

```
#dibujo div{
  position: absolute;
  width: some %;
  height: some %;
  top: some %;
  ...
}
```

It'll be more work but the whole thing should resize as you shrink the window.